# How to create a text box in powerpoint of attached design

Tags: microsoft-powerpoint

I am trying to create the following text box in power point. Any idea how to approach this?

[image]

Basically I need text boxes with left border color and a strong padding between boxes. I was trying to use tables but wasn't successful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you need to think more creatively while using PowerPoint.

I would use shapes to draw a square and then a green line on the left side of the square then I can draw a textbox inside it. Then while holding ctrl, right click on all three of these objects and then push ctrl+v on where ever you like to have it again.

I usually create one slide full of these objects that I know I would want to duplicate constantly.

The sample:
[sample design](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5aWEm.png)

Selected multiple items:
[selected items](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i4FAk.png)

I hope you find this helpful!

Comment: Yep. But it might be enough to draw just the text box and the line. Or a rectangle and the line. One less shape to keep track of.

Comment: Agreed. I thought maybe it would be easier to draw a third shape rather than adjusting the padding. I can be really lazy :)